# Windows cmd (batch) for loop

Tags: windows, loops, batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I'm having some problems with my for loop. This is what I got now:

```
@echo off
set installPrograms=CCleaner,Adobe Reader,Cute PDF Writer
for %%a in ("%installPrograms:,=" "%") do echo %%a
pause >nul
```

This outputs:

```
"CCleaner"
"Adobe Reader"
"Cute PDF Writer"
```

What I want this to output is:

```
CCleaner
Adobe Reader
Cute PDF Writer
```

So I'd like it to output those programs without the " " marks. Seems the spaces in the program names is causing problems if I change the code to something like:

```
 for %%a in (%installPrograms:,= %) do echo %%a

 Output:
 CCleaner
 Adobe
 Reader
 Cute
 PDF
 Writer
```

How can I make this work? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just replace `echo %%a` with `echo %%~a`.

The Tilde (`~`) removes any surrounding quotes (if there are any).

Described in `for /?`